# load ansible variables from dictionary depending on overgiven startup vars

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary with databases and values to this in a group_vars file like this:

```yaml
connections:
    db1:
      bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.121:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar'
      instance: '001'
      profile_name: 'user@db1'
      role: 'primary'
    db2:
      bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.21:2581/virtualschema/virtual-schema.jar'
      instance: '002'
      profile_name: 'user@db2'
      role: 'primary'
    db3:
      bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.21:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar'
      instance: '003'
      profile_name: 'user@db3'
      role: 'primary'
    db4:
      bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.131:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar'
      instance: '004'
      profile_name: 'user@db4'
      role: 'primary'
```

And a task in `main.yml` of `tasks` folder of my role which use this variables

```yaml
- name: Load S3 driver to BucketFS
  ansible.builtin.shell: /usr/bin/curl -k -X PUT -T {{ item.value.bucketfsurl }} -v
  loop: "{{ connections | dict2items }}"
  when: 'database == item.key'
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Now I start a playbook which uses the role with

```
ansible-playbook /home/david/playbook.yml -i /home/david/inventory/testhosts -e database=db1
```

When I give exactly one parameter for `database`, all works. Task will be executed one time with matching values from dictionary. But how can I handle this with more than one database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to acheive this but they all basically come down to passing a list. An easy way with extra vars is to pass a comma separated list of elements and split it.

So to pass several dbs you would use for example

```
-e databases=db1,db3
```

And then change your condition to

```yaml
  when: item.key in databases.split(',')
```

Note that you could enhance that task avoiding looping on elements to be skipped by dropping them before iterating. This is the complete optimized task:

```yaml
- name: Load S3 driver to BucketFS
  vars:
    dblist: "{{ databases.split(',') }}"
  ansible.builtin.shell: /usr/bin/curl -k -X PUT -T {{ item.value.bucketfsurl }} -v
  loop: "{{ connections | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'in', dblist) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

If you wonder, both options will still work with a single db passed as argument (without coma e.g. `-e databases=db2`) as `split` will return a list with a single element.

Here is a complete `test.yml` playbook to test (with commands printed in a debug as I can't send the curl requests)

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    connections:
      db1:
        bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.121:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar'
        instance: '001'
        profile_name: 'user@db1'
        role: 'primary'
      db2:
        bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.21:2581/virtualschema/virtual-schema.jar'
        instance: '002'
        profile_name: 'user@db2'
        role: 'primary'
      db3:
        bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.21:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar'
        instance: '003'
        profile_name: 'user@db3'
        role: 'primary'
      db4:
        bucketfsurl: 'https://1.2.3.131:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar'
        instance: '004'
        profile_name: 'user@db4'
        role: 'primary'

  tasks:
    - name: Load S3 driver to BucketFS
      vars:
        dblist: "{{ databases.split(',') }}"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Command to play: /usr/bin/curl -k -X PUT -T {{ item.value.bucketfsurl }} -v"
      loop: "{{ connections | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'in', dblist) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml -e databases=db1,db3

PLAY [test] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Load S3 driver to BucketFS] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=db1) => {
    "msg": "Command to play: /usr/bin/curl -k -X PUT -T https://1.2.3.121:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar -v"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=db3) => {
    "msg": "Command to play: /usr/bin/curl -k -X PUT -T https://1.2.3.21:2581/bucket2/virtual-schema.jar -v"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I tried this but get error:

```fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ connections | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'in', dblist) }}): dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'list'> instead."}```

So I tried without the loop but then get this:

```fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.key in database.split(',')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.key in database.split(',')): 'item' is undefined```

Comment: So I re-add the loop but removed the ```dict2items``` and I get this:

```fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f32237471a8>```

I changed ```connections``` to a list and Ansible interpret it also as list. Because:

```- debug:
          msg: 'connections is a {{ connections | type_debug }}'```

give me:

```ok: [podman_server1] => {
    "msg": "connections is a list"
}```

Comment: If `dict2items` is complaining it receives a list instead of a dict, then there is a huge differerence between the data you have paste above and the one you are currently using.

Comment: I've just anonymize the values of the dict, not more...

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I get exactly what is expected using your above data.

Comment: Interesting - for the first test I just copied your example playbook in one file and executed it. I get:

```TASK [Load S3 driver to BucketFS] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object select_or_reject at 0x7efe19153eb8>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
```

Comment: @gurbelunder You are using ansible 2.9 or lower. Ansible 2.9 as been terminated for over 2 years now. Please upgrade to a supported version (i.e. ansible-core 2.14 or newer see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html). In the mean time, you can pipe the `list` filter at the end of the loop expression. Please make sure you use supported versions of your software stack before asking for help or at the very least advertise the version you are using in your question to avoid loosing the time of people trying to answer. Thanks.

Comment: OK for versions beavior I just can use that, what my customer has. Support status wasn't clear. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

One way I found now how it works for me. The dictionary `connections` is still a dictionary and not changed.
All my databases are now an entry in my `inventory` which looks like this:

```ini
[podman_service:children]
databases

[podman_service]
server1

[databases]
db1
db2
db3
db4
```

All variables like user, host etc. coming from `group_vars.yml` file for `podman_service`. In this file also my dict `connections` is inserted.

Then each database in `inventory` has now an own `host_vars.yml` file actually only with one variable, here f.e. for `db1`

```yaml
---
  dbname: 'db1'
```

So i just put the "fake host name" into variable `dbname` to have a variable to work with. Sure there is a bit better way for this a bit more dynamically.

And my task now looks like this

```yaml
- name: Load S3 driver to BucketFS
  ansible.builtin.shell: /usr/bin/curl -k -X PUT -T {{ item.value.bucketfsurl }} -v
  loop: "{{ connections | dict2items }}"
  when: 'dbname== item.key'
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Nearly unchanged but just `when` condition works with another variable `dbname`.

Now I can start my playbook with

```bash
ansible-playbook /home/david/playbook.yml -i /home/david/inventory/testhosts -e database=db1,db2
```

and Ansible would just execute for `db1` and `db2` and the other will be skipped.

Unfortunately output of `ansible-playbook` command is a bit more, because it do a `gather_facts` now also for each database entry which is the same server as `server1` because databases gets it `ansible_host` over `group_vars.yml` file of group `podman_service`. But that is just a detail :)